# Сортировка списка по значению

Tags: c++, list

нужно сортировать данный список по возрастанию стипендии( а после вывести имена студентов в новом порядке). Как это можно сделать? Еще интересно, как при работе листа с типом struct обращаться к переменным.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int marks[4];
    char name[32];
    int scholarship; // стипендия
    Node(int* marks, char* name, int scholarship) {
        this->marks[4] = marks[4];
        this->name[32] = name[32];
        this->scholarship = scholarship;
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    char namee[30];
    int volume;
    int mark[4];
    int n;
    list<struct Node> List;
    cout << "Сколько студентов желаете ввести ? "; cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Введите имя " << i + 1 << " студента: "; cin >> namee;
        cout << "Введите оценки: ";
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cin >> mark[j];
        }
        cout << "Введите размер стипендии: "; cin >> volume;
        Node node(mark, namee, volume);
        List.push_back(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: У `list` есть метод `sort`. Передайте ему компаратор, который сравнивает студентов по полю стипендии, и дело в шляпе.

Comment: `this->name[32]=...` - ошибка доступа к памяти, прога упадёт. Аргументы надо передавать с помощью копирования `strncpy`.

Comment: @Harry Впервые узнал о компараторах, но вот попробовал создать функцию bool foo(Node* a, Node* b) {
 return a->scholarship < b->scholarship;
} Правильно ли я сделал запись ? И если да, то как в методе sort, передать разные объекты Node;     List.sort(foo(  ));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не могу поместиться в комментарий, отвечу про `list::sort()` здесь.

Чтобы отсортировать `list<Node>` нужно передать в [функцию `sort()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort) соответствующий компаратор. Как сказано, его сигнатура должна быть подобна

```
bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
```

т.е. никаких указателей! В вашем случае это

```
bool foo(const Node& a, const Node& b) { return a.scholarship < b.scholarship; }
```

а при вызове надо просто передать саму функцию (указатель на нее, не результат ее выполнения) в `sort`:

```
List.sort(foo);
```

Comment: Все понял, спасибо большое.